# Creating a hook into my facebook app from another site

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

new to facebook dev and I have read the basics to get a site up and running using the canvas setup. Nice and simple, I have also got the integration with users working ok (i.e. the signed_request).

I was wondering how it works with "sending/posting" data from one site that is anonymous (my own external to facebook) to the facebook site.

The flow I'm after is a user is looking at some content my site A (my own external site) and then clicks the "share on facebook" button (or whatever), which sends the user (and the data they were looking at) to the site B (my facebook app) to which they authenticate and then (and this is the part I dont get) can see that content on their personalised homepage within site B.

So is there a way to POST some kind of data to the facebook site? Or do I need to do something else here?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You use the facebook API located here:

http://github.com/facebook/csharp-sdk

The .zip download includes the api that you can compile, as well as a sample project that uses it.

Reference: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/395/

**EDIT**

Here is some more info regarding the facebook graph api. I think you'll find everything you need in here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: cool I'll take a look at that, Im assuming it has an example of exactly what Im asking for?

Comment: The C# API wrapper only has a very rudimentary example of how to use the wrapper, not really the API. See my edit; you'll find exactly what you want at the link provided.